# Optional attribute in activemodel serializer in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers, rails-api

I have following two Serializer class. In index controller I want skip loading project_products, only show/edit method I want to fetch project_product details.

```
class ProjectSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      attributes :id, :name, :category, :project_category_id, :status, :description
      has_many :project_products
    end

class ProjectProductSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :quantity
end
```

Controller:

```
  def index
    respond_with @projects
  end

def load_projects
    @projects = current_organization.projects.includes(:project_category)
  end
```

Comment: To sum up, you do not want to load project_products in show/edit ?

Comment: hi @Defoncesko Just opposite i want to load project_products in show/edit but not in index

Comment: Show your views & controllers codes please.

Comment: def index
        respond_with @projects
      end

Comment: Format of response is json

Comment: So you want to remove project_products from your JSON response ?

Comment: Yes, i want to remove project_products form JSON response for index function

Answer (score 0):

Try to override association methods

```
 class ProjectSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      attributes :id, :name, :category, :project_category_id, :status, :description
      has_many :project_products

    def project_products
        if current_page?(edit_path_url)
            object.comments
        else
            object.comments = nil
    end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but when i place the code `respond_with @projects.to_json(:except => ["project_products"])` it ignores my active serializer and showing all fields form projects table

Comment: That 's what you are using ? https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

Comment: Did you try to override association methods and inside select what you need to return with conditions on path ?

Comment: Simply i want to fetch some fields from project table when listing projects. And want product listing along with project details (not all fields) in project details page. obviously using activeModelSerializer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "except" param when creating the serializer instance:

```
respond_with @projects, except: project_products
```

(when the index controller action)